# How can I get Apache httpd web server to process mod_include directives after the file been processed by Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I currently have Apache httpd and Tomcat running on the same server and the DocumentRoot of my httpd instance is the same as the webapps directory of tomcat. mod_jk is used to connect httpd and Tomcat.

Using this setting in my httpd.conf file allowed the mod_include INCLUDES filter to parse SSI directives after Tomcat processed JSP pages.

```
<LocationMatch "\.jsp$">
  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
</LocationMatch>
```

Now I have moved Tomcat to a different server and everything is working except for httpd is not parsing JSP pages after Tomcat process the mod_include directives. e.g. #include, #if, #set show in the source code in the browser.

I am using httpd 2.4 and Tomcat 8

Comments in the mod_include SSIStartTag documentation for httpd suggest this can be done. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#ssistarttag